# app-release.apk showing "Parse error: There is a problm parsing application"

Tags: android, android-studio, developer-tools

I have checked many answers but none of them helped

1. I am running it 5.1.1 android, and in build.gradle it is minSdkVersion as 15 so it should work.
2. I am able to run app-debug.apk on same device without any issue.
3. I have not renamed apk file after that, i have signed it for the first time manually in android studio.

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "com.example.raghav.pokemonfinder"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 23
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled true
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }

       packagingOptions {
           exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
           exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
           exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

       }
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
       apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
       compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.2'
       compile 'me.sargunvohra.lib:pokekotlin:2.2.3'
   }
   ```

and here is my androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.raghav.pokemonfinder">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name="Utils.PokeMonFinder"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" />
        <activity android:name=".MapsShowActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SubmitPokemon" />
        <activity android:name=".PokemonDetailActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".MyPokemonActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Where and how did you get the error?

Comment: @s-hunter : i completed my app and then signed it from studio manually following all instrustions and produced app-release.apk , then i tried to install this apk on my device, then i got this error

Comment: Also on my device i have "Install from unknown source" checked so not a problem with that as well

Comment: You wrote _"I have checked many answers"_ but that's doubtful: [you're the only person in the world with this error message according to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=“Parse+error%3A+There+is+a+problm+parsing+application”).